# GET request to API with basic authentication works with browser but not in Postman - used to work earlier

Tags: postman, basic-authentication, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm trying to perform a simple GET request to the SAP IntegrationContent API. Up until today it was working fine on Postman, but it has recently started to return the source code of an authentication page, instead of the actual data.

The peculiar behavior I have observed is that the data is returned if I perform the request from my browser without any issue. For this reason, I used Postman Interceptor to clone the request so I could troubleshoot any discrepancy. Unfortunately, even after performing the exact same request, Postman still retrieves the authentication page.

Here is the browser request as from what's been captured by Postman Interceptor:
[image: Request sent by browser, captured by Postman Interceptor]

This is the data returned by the browser:

```
<service xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:base="https://*my host*-trial.cfapps.us10-001.hana.ondemand.com:443/api/v1/">
<workspace>
<atom:title>Default</atom:title>
<collection href="TraceMessageProperties">
<atom:title>TraceMessageProperties</atom:title>
</collection>
<collection href="ExternalLoggingEvents">
<atom:title>ExternalLoggingEvents</atom:title>
</collection>
...
```

While this is what Postman returns:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" />
            <script>
document.cookie="fragmentAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.hash)+";path=/";document.cookie="locationAfterLogin="+encodeURIComponent(location.href.split('#')[0].split(location.host)[1])+";path=...
```

Could anyone point me to where the issue could be?

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue, also with SAP. Seems to be related to cookies. Did you find anything?

Comment: @CodrinStrîmbei unfortunately nothing yet. Though this was for an experiment of mine, so there was no urgency to get it solved.

Comment: thank you for the response. I've also posted it on SAP Community: https://answers.sap.com/questions/13972249/why-doesnt-sap-ci-odata-api-v1-working-using-the-o.html